# Impact of migrating instances

Tags: bestpractice, migration, org

My  org is being pushed from na14 from na12 instance, I have a checklist of items mentioned below (not a complete list). I wanted to check with folks out here who have gone through this, if I need to be aware of something major

We have this list so far: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-prepare-for-a-migration&language=en_US

1) Email templates having hard coded instance name.

2) Static resources having hard coded instance name.

3) Apex classes / visual force pages having hard coded instance name.

4) Custom labels/ custom settings having hard coded instance name.

5) SSO settings having hard coded instance name.

6) Contacted 3rd party apps to let them know about the migration.

7) API's are part of impact analysis .

Can you guys point me to more places / provide feedback to be aware of before things become irreversible?

Thanks in advance.